# MySQL script optimization

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables, `graphics`, `rasp`:

[image]

My query works, but its too too slow (LIMIT 1 about 200+ seconds, and its only with about 50 000 records).

I need to select 2 records in 1 from `graphics` which are (result record http://oi57.tinypic.com/2edbhvk.jpg):

```
- with the same graphics.`trainid`
- with the same graphics.`date`
- first record graphics.`stationid1` = rasp.`stationfrom`
- first record graphics.`comment` near rasp.`from` (about +- 30 minutes)
- second record graphics.`stationid1` = rasp.`stationto`
- second record graphics.`comment` near rasp.`to` (about +- 30 minutes)
```

My query:

```
SELECT r.num, r.from, r.to, g.id, g.comment, g.stationid1, g2.id, g2.comment, g2.stationid1 
FROM graphics g, graphics g2, rasp r 
WHERE abs(timestampdiff(minute,g.dt,CONCAT(g.date,' ',r.from)))<30 
    AND g2.id>g.id 
    AND g.stationid1=r.stationfrom 
    AND abs(timestampdiff(minute,g2.dt,CONCAT(g2.date,' ',r.to)))<30 
    AND g2.stationid2=r.stationto 
    AND g.date=g2.date 
    AND g.trainid=g2.trainid 
group by g.date, g.comment 
LIMIT 1
```

I tryed to use joins, but it executes about the same time as only with select.

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about the query?

Comment: EXPLAIN http://oi59.tinypic.com/2eej4gg.jpg

Comment: Barmar, indexes solved my problem, thank you